# Document doesn't show the list of figures (LaTeX)

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, listings

I have the problem that `LaTeX` doesn't show the `List of figures` and `List of Listings`. I don't know where the problem is.

I'm working with TeXstudio and the code was defined as follows:

```
\usepackage{acl2013}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Testcode is here}\label{lst:Testcode is here},frame=single] 
//here is the code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1.jpg}
    \caption{That is a pic}
    \label{fig: That is a pic}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

### Both lists remain empty. Can anyone tell me what the problem is??

EDIT:
That's the content of my Filelist:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 acl2013.sty    
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
latexsym.sty    1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
 caption.sty    2015/09/17 v3.3-111 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2015/09/20 v1.7-115 caption3 kernel (AR)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
   t1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
   ulasy.fd    1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
   t1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pcr.
  omsptm.fd    
attacheddev.jpg    Graphic file (type jpg)
buildapp.jpg    Graphic file (type jpg)
welcomeapp.jpg    Graphic file (type jpg)
 devmenu.jpg    Graphic file (type jpg)
 content.jpg    Graphic file (type jpg)
 acl2013.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you compile twice? If I extent your 'fragment' to a document I get both lists filled (after two compilations)

Comment: I have compiled more than twice..It's no use..

Comment: What is `acl2013`? Again, your example isn't minimal and not compilable. Adding `\documentclass{article}`, removing `acl2013` and adding the `demo` option to `graphicx`, I get the `List of ...` after two compilations. I suspect a `\nofiles` directive somewhere in the preamble, perhaps!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ´acl2013´ is a template for creating academic papers. Now when I add the ´demo´ to ´graphicx´ all my pics become to a blackbox.

Comment: Yes, of course, black boxes to make the document compilable, which isn't the case without `demo`, since nobody except of you has this image file `pic1`. Again: Apart from the `acl2013` 'template` your example works!

Comment: pic1 was only an example. I have replace it :). But the list of figures and the list of listings are still empty.. I'm desperate

Comment: Apparently you are doing something completely wrong, actually. I can't tell what it is, but nobody else has this issue with your code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, I've tested the answer of Herbert. The following result was visible. I have replaced pic1.jpg with an existed pic -> buildapp.jpg. When I replaced the image the lists disappeared. Could you test the package acl2013. You can download it from this site: http://www.acl2013.org/site/call.html

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Only when I'm using \usepackage{acl2013} the lists become empty.

Comment: That's what I suspected already. Such 'rubbish' templates should be banned

Comment: @yuro: is the Class available for download?

Comment: You mean the package?

Comment: @Herbert: I've downloaded the package! `\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}`  -- OMG ;-)

Comment: *"´acl2013´ is a template for creating academic papers."* As far as i can see, that is a template for conference submission with a deadline in 2013. Are you sure that is the correct template to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the missing `List of...` is, that the `acl2013` package does
use following lines

```
% We're never going to need a table of contents, so just flush it to
% save space --- suggested by drstrip@sandia-2
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{}
```

i.e. `\addcontentsline` does nothing and there's no change to write a `.lof` or `.lol` etc.

This `effective` code is annoying, but storing the old definition before `acl2013` is loaded and restore after its loaded cures the problem

```
\let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\usepackage{acl2013}
\let\addcontentsline\origaddcontentsline
```

This is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\usepackage{acl2013}
\let\addcontentsline\origaddcontentsline
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Testcode is here}\label{lst:Testcode is here},frame=single] 
//here is the code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1.jpg}
    \caption{That is a pic}
    \label{fig: That is a pic}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\origaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\usepackage{acl2013}
\let\addcontentsline\origaddcontentsline
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}  % Adds figure numbering 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.1 etc. 
\AtBeginDocument{%
\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}  % Adds figure numbering 1.1, 1.2, ..., 2.1 etc. 
}

\begin{document}

\section{My first section}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Testcode is here}\label{lst:Testcode is here},frame=single] 
//here is the code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1.jpg}
    \caption{That is a pic}
    \label{fig: That is a pic}
\end{figure}


\listoffigures

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST CHRIS!!!!! MANY MANY MANY THANKS!!!  This was the solution... You've safed my day :)

Comment: do you know how to set the numeration about the listings and figures.. for the moment it is just numerated. (1. ... 2. ... 3. ...) but I want to set the chapter.. for example (1.1 this is the first pic, 1.2 second pic, 2.1 first pic in chapter 2. and so on)

Comment: @yuro: `acl2013` uses the `abstract` environment, which is not available with the `book` class (if you want to have chapters, no need `book` or `report` for example). However, I've added a `\section` version with `1.1` etc. numbering

Comment: nice it works. How is this for listings? I've tried to add the following \counterwithin{lstlisting}{section} but that's the wrong way.

Comment: @yuro: `lstlisting` is defined after `\begin{document}` (I don't know why), but see my change in the update (the lines with `\AtBeginDocument{...}`

Comment: Thanksss it works :).. Do you have skills in citavi?

Comment: @yuro: I don't know what citavi is -- and it would lead to something different than this question

Answer (score 3):

you have to run the document twice. However, use package `caption` and `\captionof` if you do not want the image to float around.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Testcode is here}\label{lst:Testcode is here},frame=single] 
    //here is the code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{That is a pic}\label{fig: That is a pic}
\end{center}

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]

The filelist:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
 caption.sty    2016/02/02 v3.3-136 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/02/02 v1.7-136 caption3 kernel (AR)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Comment: I've tried this, but also doesn't work. I don't know why. I have updated my post with all packages I'm using.

Comment: what does my example exactly produce with your system. Compare my filelist (you get it with `\listfiles`, ee edited code) with your list, it is at the end of the logfile.?

Comment: I've added the content of my filelist.